# Error in proof by contrapositive.

Tags: logic, proof-verification, foundations

Prove the assertion: if $x<-1$, then $x^2>1$

I am trying to prove this by contrapositive and so far I have

$x^2\ge1$ then $x\ge-1$

$x^2-1\ge0$

$(x-1)(x+1)\ge0$

$-1\le x \le 1$

which does not prove what I am trying to prove.

Comment: The implication from second last to last line is incorrect.

Comment: Alternately, you can see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112657/supply-a-proof-for-the-assertion/2112676#2112676

Comment: You didn't do contrapositive, which would be: if $\;x^2\rlap{\,\,/}>1\;$ , then $\;x\rlap{\;\,/}<-1\;$ , or what is the same : $\;x^2\le1\implies x\ge-1\;$ .

Answer (score 2):

Why not prove it directly?

$$x<-1\implies \text{ (since}\;x\;\text{ is negative)} \;\; x^2>-x>1$$

the last inequality being the very first times $\;-1\;$ .